# Angularjs When I click on link in View 1 I am Unable to Navigate to View 2

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, view, controllers

I searched stackoverflow for a simple answer. Yes. I believe I am missing something simple.  It is all in the learning process.  Thanks for taking a look.

Update.  I now am able to Navigate to the moreinfo.html View but I am Not Binding the Data.

Heading
=======!
[Before modifications. index.html launches but 'View More Info' Links do Not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkxxq.jpg)
[image]

Heading
=======!
[After modifications. 'View More Info' links work but No Bound Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYBRd.jpg)

[image]

Heading
=======!
[moreinfo.html  navigates fine to the view but again No Bound Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1deMZ.jpg)

[image]

```
stats.html  
//Main Point of Entry.    
<h2>Soccer</h2>
    Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="playersFilter.name" />
    <br /><br />
    <ul>
    <li>Sort By Category</li>
    </ul>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="doSort('Attempts')">Attempts</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('Goals')">Goals</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('Assists')">Assists</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('Fouls')">Fouls</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('Date')">Date</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('average')">Average</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter:playersFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
            <td>{{ player.Goals }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.Attempts  }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.Assists }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.Fouls }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.date | date }}</td>
            <td>{{player.Goals / player.Attempts | number:2}}</td>   
            <td><a href ="#/moreinfo/{{ player.id }}"> View More Info</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <span>Total Games: {{ players.length }}</span>
```

This is the page that I want to Navigate to when I Click on the link 'View More Info' from the stat.html page.  But nothing happens and there are not any error hints in in the console or network tabs in Chrome Dev Tools.

```
moreinfo.html  
<h2>More Information</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>TeamImage </th>
        <th>oppImage </th>
    </tr>
    <!--<tr ng-repeat ="player in players">-->
        <td>{{player.Image}}</td>
        <td>{{player.teamImage}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have embedded the json.

```
statsController.js  

    function() {

    var StatsController = function ($scope) {

        $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
           $scope.sortBy = propName;
           $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        };    
$scope.getAverage = function(){
    var average = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.player.Goals.length; i++){
        var a = $scope.player.Goals[i];
        average += (player.Attempts / player.Goals);
    }
    return average;
}    

    $scope.players = [
    {
    id:1,
    games: [
           {
            "Goals": 1,
            "Attempts": 6,
            "Image": "http://www.soccer1.png",
            "opp": "USA",
            "Assists": 0,
            "team": "ECU",
            "Fouls": 1,
            "teamImage": "http://www.soccerTeam1.png",
            "date": "2014-03-31"
          },
          {
            "Goals": 0,
            "Attempts": 3,
            "Image": "http://www.soccer2.png",
            "opp": "CHI",
            "Assists": 1,
            "team": "KAZ",
            "Fouls": 1,
            "teamImage": "http://www.soccerTeam2.png",
            "date": "2014-04-02"
          }
        ]
},
{
    id:2,
    games: [
           {
            "Goals": 2,
            "Attempts": 2,
            "Image": "http://www.soccer22.png",
            "opp": "USA",
            "Assists": 0,
            "team": "ECU",
            "Fouls": 1,
            "teamImage": "http://www.soccerTeam22.png",
            "date": "2014-03-31"
          },
          {
            "Goals": 3,
            "Attempts": 3,
            "Image": "http://www.soccer33.png",
            "opp": "CHI",
            "Assists": 1,
            "team": "KAZ",
            "Fouls": 1,
            "teamImage": "http://www.soccerTeam33.png",
            "date": "2014-04-02"
          }
        ]
    }
];
};   
    StatsController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    angular.module('sportsApp')
      .controller('StatsController', StatsController);    
}());
```

I have embedded json below. This is a lot of redundant code.    Ideally, I want to have all of the json in a separate file and use a factory but I am doing this step by step.

```
    moreinfoController.js
    (function() {

    var MoreInfoController = function ($scope, $routeParams) {
        // get to the route and the playerId

        var playerId = $routeParams.playerId;
        $scope.games = null;

        function init() {
            for (var i= 0, len=$scope.players.length; i<len; i++){
                if($scope.players[i].id === parseInt(playerId)) {
                    $scope.games = $scope.players[i].games;
                    break;
                }
            }  
        }
// init();       

$scope.players = [
    {
    id:1,
    games: [
           {
            "Goals": 1,
            "Attempts": 6,
            "Image": "http://www.soccer1.png",
            "opp": "USA",
            "Assists": 0,
            "team": "ECU",
            "Fouls": 1,
            "teamImage": "http://www.soccerTeam1.png",
            "date": "2014-03-31"
          },
          {
            "Goals": 0,
            "Attempts": 3,
            "Image": "http://www.soccer2.png",
            "opp": "CHI",
            "Assists": 1,
            "team": "KAZ",
            "Fouls": 1,
            "teamImage": "http://www.soccerTeam2.png",
            "date": "2014-04-02"
          }
        ]
},
{
    id:2,
    games: [
           {
            "Goals": 2,
            "Attempts": 2,
            "Image": "http://www.soccer22.png",
            "opp": "USA",
            "Assists": 0,
            "team": "ECU",
            "Fouls": 1,
            "teamImage": "http://www.soccerTeam22.png",
            "date": "2014-03-31"
          },
          {
            "Goals": 3,
            "Attempts": 3,
            "Image": "http://www.soccer33.png",
            "opp": "CHI",
            "Assists": 1,
            "team": "KAZ",
            "Fouls": 1,
            "teamImage": "http://www.soccerTeam33.png",
            "date": "2014-04-02"
          }
        ]
    }
];
    init();
    };

    MoreInfoController.$inject = ['$scope','$routeParams'];

    angular.module('sportsApp')
      .controller('MoreInfoController', MoreInfoController);    
    }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link says

```
<td><a href ="#/moreinfo{{ player.id}}"> View More Info</a></td>
```

but I can not see any id property of player in your json.

It seems this to be an issue.

Additionally, it seems you are missing a / as well after moreinfo in your href.

Comment: thanks. I am abot to edit code above.  still missing a piece of the logic in my mind.  I actually have 5 players and I gave them each an id.  Only 2 of them in the example and only 2 games each.  I read your profile.  I too have a priority in life and am on a similar wavelength as you are.

Comment: Can you please create plunker? It will be much easier to debug.

Comment: thanks.  i have been working on it.  this may not be the original code from the post but it is close.  i really appreciate the help.  there is just a bit of the logic i am missing conceptually.
http://plnkr.co/edit/GKMOeNwNxLa9q8aucz4h

Comment: i am here.  i JUST got link to work and will update plunkr. thanks. do i need to use @nikhil ?

Comment: you are right.  plunkr not working even though i added the cdns for angular.js and angular-routes-min.js  So the link to get to the moreinfo VIEW works for me but I can Not get the data to bind.  I have included the images in my folder  soccerSnoopy1.jpeg and soccerSnoopy2.jpeg. I cannot add them in plunkr though. thanks

Comment: Not a problem. Give me some time. I will be looking at the issue again.

Comment: You need to update  <!--<tr ng-repeat ="player in players">-->
        <td>{{player.Image}}</td>
        <td>{{player.teamImage}}</td>
    </tr> to  <tr ng-repeat ="game in games">
        <td>{{game.Image}}</td>
        <td>{{game.teamImage}}</td>
    </tr>

Comment: In simpler meanings, in your more info page, there is nothing called player in your scope. It is games. So you need to iterate on games and then extract information from that.

Comment: nikhil, are you able to add 2 points to my reputation. it will allow for me to chat.  are red box just popped up suggesting this. and i just went over character allotment.

Comment: what you say makes total sense. still not binding the data.I have  nested data.  games is nested inside of players.I think that I have to get to it somehow.
moreinfoControllerSoccerData.js has $scope as such:
$scope.players = [
{ id:1, 
games: [
          {"id":1,Goals":1,"Attempts":6,"Photo":"http://soccerSnoopy1.jpg",
            "opp": "USA","Assists": 0, "team": "ECU","Fouls": 1,
            "teamPhoto": "http://www.soccerTeam1.png","date": 
}
I changed the code exactly as you suggested but still Not getting the Bound Data.
I had change the name 'image' to 'photo' (image reserved word).

Comment: @shareyourpeace - I have voted for your question - hope that helped

Comment: thanks a bunch. If you have time to chat at some time let me know.  I have been using online courses, docs, videos to learn Angular.Then I modify code to make my own examples. My priority is Not to just copy code.  I want to understand the logic.  I've inquired with the guy whose course I have taken & asked him to explain the logic of how to drill down into the nested json data using a loop. So far, he has responded but not with the logic.  Hopefully this will happen. will update
http://shareyourpeace2.info/projectAngularSportsStatsSoccer/#/
 http://plnkr.co/edit/7kzjYwmjllGDGDyoyrE8?p=preview

Comment: To start with update your moreInfoControllerSoccerData.js. you are calling your init function prior to setting players in $scope, because of which $scope.players is coming as undefined in init function

Comment: Also, I am available for chat from now till next 30 mins. Let me know if you around

Comment: I just missed you.  been updating stuff.  And unbelievable !  I just tried to chat and a red pop up just said 'Now we need 20 to chat.'  I can chat through gmail if and when. thanks

Comment: @shareyourpeace - i have to go somewhere. We can chat in 2 hours from now. My email id is nikhil.agw@gmail.com